# Mysql Subquery Unknown Column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

With the following query I am getting the error **unknown column a.id in where clause**. I'm basically trying to add a limit of 5 to what would have been two left joins. Is it possible to rewrite this query so it can work?

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(body,' ') FROM (
            SELECT c.body FROM c WHERE c.id IN (
                SELECT id_c FROM b WHERE b.id_a=a.id
            )
            LIMIT 5
        ) c
    )) AS contents
FROM
a
```

Full SQLfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1822/3

Find_in_set works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d43bb/1 but it is extremely slow with large datasets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
SELECT a.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.body,' ') AS contents
FROM a 
  LEFT JOIN b
  ON b.id_a = a.id 
  LEFT JOIN c
  ON  b.id_c = c.id
  AND c.id <= COALESCE(
    (  SELECT ci.id
       FROM c AS ci
         JOIN b AS bi
         ON  bi.id_c = ci.id
       WHERE b.id_a = bi.id_a
       ORDER BY ci.id
       LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4 
    ), 10000000000)
GROUP BY a.id ;
```

a variation:

```
-- variation 2
SELECT a.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.body,' ') AS contents
FROM a 
  LEFT JOIN b
    JOIN c
    ON  b.id_c = c.id
    AND c.id <= COALESCE(
      (  SELECT ci.id
         FROM c AS ci
           JOIN b AS bi
           ON  bi.id_c = ci.id
         WHERE b.id_a = bi.id_a
         ORDER BY ci.id
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4 
      ), 10000000000)
  ON b.id_a = a.id 
GROUP BY a.id ;
```

and two more, all using the same basic pattern:

```
-- variation 3
SELECT a.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.body,' ') AS contents
FROM a 
  LEFT JOIN b
    ON  b.id_a = a.id 
    AND b.id_c <= COALESCE(
      (  SELECT bi.id_c 
         FROM b AS bi
         WHERE b.id_a = bi.id_a
         ORDER BY bi.id_c
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4 
      ), 10000000000)
  LEFT JOIN c
  ON b.id_c = c.id
GROUP BY a.id ;

-- variation 4
SELECT a.id,
       ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.body,' ')
         FROM b
         LEFT JOIN c
         ON b.id_c = c.id
         WHERE b.id_a = a.id 
           AND b.id_c <= COALESCE(
             ( SELECT bi.id_c 
               FROM b AS bi
               WHERE b.id_a = bi.id_a
               ORDER BY bi.id_c
               LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4 
             ), 10000000000)
       ) AS contents
FROM a ;
```

Tested in **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/716e6c/31)**.

Comment: variation 3 has a join less than the first two. It may be a bit more efficient.

Comment: Yes, variation 3 seems most efficient. In fact it is loads faster

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it does not work (there seems to be limitations in MySQL that hide variables that aught to be visible). I would try to rewrite it using JOINs. This is tested on `10.2.14-MariaDB`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',GROUP_CONCAT(x.body,' '))  
FROM (
    SELECT b.id_a, c.body, row_number() over (partition by b.id_a) as n
    FROM c
    JOIN b 
        ON c.id = b.id_c
    GROUP BY b.id_a, c.body
) x
JOIN a
    ON x.id_a=a.id
WHERE n <= 5;
```

Here a window function `row_number()` is used to enumerate c.body per b.id_a. This attribute can then be used to limit number of bodys that gets concatenated.

I'm not sure why `GROUP BY b.id_a, c.body` is required when adding `row_number()`, looks like a bug in the implementation (haven't checked, perhaps it is mentioned in the docs).

Comment: group_concat_max_len is already set by us but the query is slow with large datasets. If we LIMIT the join it only selects a subset and is a lot quicker.

If there were 1M left join rows it would select all of them and then group_concat after up until the limit which is inefficient. If we replace a.id with an actual number it works perfectly and selects a lot quicker. But of course mysql doesn't let me add a.id to the nested subquery

Comment: The edited answer seems to work but unfortunately it is a multitude slower then just left joining without a limit.

Comment: What indexes are there?

Comment: Primary on a.id and Primary on b.id_a,b.id_c and Primary on c.id